# Is it possible to dynamically add (check-marked) rows to another tab/sheet? Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

## Quick Brief

I have a sheet with 3 tabs (Overview, Book 1, Book 2). The first tab (Overview) contains a lot of rows (Programs) with a lot of columns (information). I want to dynamically add these rows (Programs) to another tab (Book) whenever I checkmark them for that location, **if possible**!. To give you a visual idea:

### Tab: Overview

[image: Overview]

### Tab: Book 1

[image: Book 1]

### Tab: Book 2

[image: Book 2]

#### Current solution

My current solution, for now, is making filters for every Book-name containing an 'x' and sort the programs alphabetically, and just copy-paste them to that given tab (book-location). However, this example above is just a tiny fraction of my actual document. I have over 300 programs and over 20 different books which have to be updated every-time I add or delete a program, which is time-consuming. Again, I'm not sure if the above is possible or if it needs another setup to achieve the same. Any idea/solution would be much grateful!

Comment: programmatically you are going to need an `onEdit` trigger but the performance of the current [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66224122/11225291) would be way better, unless you specifically want to use `google-apps-script`

Comment: @Marios I wasn't sure how complicated the code could be so I added the tag `google-apps-script` as well, but thnx for the `onEdit` suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **query** function to achieve this:

For example put formula in **Book 1 Cell A1** :

```
=QUERY({Overview!A1:H},"Select * where Col7 ='x' ")
```

Similarly in **Book2 Cell A1**

```
=QUERY({Overview!A1:H},"Select * where Col8 ='x' ")
```

Comment: Yeah QUERY! Thank you so much. However, I don't want to copy over the 'x''s in my book-tabs (see images). Only copy over A1:F in this case. Is that possible as well?

Comment: @Jonathan change `Select *` to `Select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6`

Comment: @Marios That's exactly what I needed, thnx a lot!